# Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF. How to troubleshoot this docker error

Tags: docker, docker-pull

I installed docker in ubuntu. hello-world repository is not there by default locally, so I was trying to run pull command in docker,but getting EOF error of docker registry-

```
*root@btppp01vm1358:~# docker pull hello-world*
```

*Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF*

Please help I am beginner in docker

Comment: Set proxy in docker if internet proxy is enabled in your environment

https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/docker/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-docker-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Set proxy in docker if internet proxy is enabled in your environment
Please use this link
[Follow this link](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/docker/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-docker-on-ubuntu/)

or follow below steps

**Creating Proxy Configuration**

1. Create a new directory for our Docker service configurations.

   `sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
2. Create a file called proxy.conf in our configuration directory.

   `sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf`
3. Add the following contents, changing the values to match your environment.

   `[Service]
    Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.hostname:8080"
    Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://myproxy.hostname:8080/"
    Environment="NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"`

   Save your changes and exit the text editor.
4. Reload the daemon configuration.

   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Restart Docker to apply our changes.

   `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`
   After the service is restarted Docker should be able to pull
   images from external repositories. You can test this by
   attempting to pull down an image. If the download completes and
   does not timeout, your proxy settings have been applied.

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). It's better to clearly separate code lines from explanations etc.